# Can My Program Detect if the connected Client Socket is via LAN (Local) or WAN (Remote)?

Tags: sockets, delphi

Can My Program Detect if the connected Client Socket on Port, say '4000', is over LAN (Local) or WAN (Remote) ?
Can InternetGetConnectedStateEx command help ?

I need it to understand if my customer is using LAN edition of my Application over WAN.

I use Delphi Seattle on Windows OS.

Regards
Allan

Comment: When a user connects by WAN it’s IP-address will be a ‘public/internet’ IP-address. When using IPv4 take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4. But basicly any address not belonging to the local network can be seen as WAN.

Comment: Typically the machines running my Client side application will have dynamic IP, whereas the Server machine will have a Static IP. How will I interpret if the Server IP is of a Local Network ? Also it may have IPV6.

Answer (score 0):

*ALL* clients connected to your server are on the same LAN as your server, otherwise they couldn't reach your server at all.  But, in the case of a client connecting from the outside world through a NAT/router, the end client will be connected to the NAT/router, and then the NAT/router will be connected to your server.  So, if you want to know if a client is connected to your server via the WAN, your server will need to know/discover the NAT/router's LAN IP address ahead of time, and then it can check whether a connected client's IP address matches the NAT/router's IP address or not.

Comment: In my Application Settings (On Server) I accept the Address all clients must use to connect to the Server. My customers are free to put in any address in that settings. It can be a Public IP or Private IP or DDNS etc. My aim is to charge the remote client machine a higher fee than the local client machines.

Comment: @Aura it is fairly trivial to have the server app enumerate the list of local IPs of the machine it is running on (via the Win32 API `GetAdaptersInfo()`/`GetAdaptersAddresses()` functions). Any address entered that is not an IP on that list, or a DNS name that resolves to such an IP, is clearly not local to the server's LAN

Comment: That answers My query for this scenario. Just one more scenario is when my client connects to a  FTP Server on NAS (Local) or FTP (Web) can I differentiate ? The difference if that my Delphi Application is not running on the Server side.

Comment: @Remi when using port forewarding on your router, isn’t the external IP-address known at the server? I thought it was....

Comment: I am using the external IP address via port forwarding but my Client side cannot differentiate when my application is not running on server. I can use sequences like 192.168 for private etc but that check will fail for ipv6 and DDNS

Comment: @R.Hoek no, the router's external IP is not generally known to the LAN machines, but it is not hard to discover the IP, using uPNP, or querying an external IP lookup website

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did nit mean the server’s public IP but the clients IP. This way Aura can determine WAN clients and let those be charged more. Thats what he’s asking as far as I can understand.

Comment: @R.Hoek you have understood my requirement correctly, but even if i get to know client's public IP it will not help as i am not using that anywhere.

Comment: @aura but then i dont understand your problem: you want to ‘detect if a client socket is connected over wan’ then the socket client/remote ip will be a wan IP and then you can detect that based on the ip address. This works for ipv4 and ipv6. But ipv6 has other public/wan scopes off course. (Based on the fact your checking it server side)

Comment: @R.Hoek that goes right back to my answer. If the server queries the client's IP, and the client is connected via the WAN, the IP will be the router's IP, not the client's IP, because the router is the one actually connected to the server on the client's behalf, not the client directly

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, then my understanding of nat/port-forewarding is probebly incorrect: I thought port-forewarding would onky route the external packet to a internal device, but leave the sending ip-address onchanged as this information is needed to send data back to the client (or isn’t this default ip behaviour)?

Comment: Could you please tell me in simple terms if it is possible to understand from Client side (FTP Client) if the connection is via LAN or WAN ?

Comment: @R.Hoek your understanding is incorrect. When the router receives a packet from the WAN, it forwards the packet to the server using the router's LAN IP/port as the sender. The server never sees the client's WAN IP/port. When the server sends a packet to the router's LAN IP/port, the router forwards the packet to the corresponding client using the router's WAN IP/port as the sender. The client never sees the server's LAN IP/port.

Comment: @Aura that has already been answered. Please re-read what has already been said